# Unable to run compiled .classes from the command line

Tags: java

I am having some issues running my compiled java code from the command line. I have written it and compiled it using the IntelliJ IDE (where everything runs fine if done within the IDE), but wish to now run it from the command line.

Compiling from the command like (using javac) also works fine, but running (with java) does not.

I am almost certain this is a classpath issue but cannot seem to fix it. From my searching prior to posting this I found a post telling me to run the "set PATH=\%PATH\%;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin" command and then try running java. I have also tried various arguements I have found for -cp and -classpath. The error is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Share/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Share.class
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: Share.class.  Program will exit.
```

Comment: Can you paste the command as well?

Comment: I've tried: java Share java -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin" Share and several similar variations

Comment: Do you actually have the Share.class file in the directory where you are executing? Maybe try java -cp . Share (the dot stands for the current directory)

Comment: No reason to set class path to the location of java.exe. Just run it in the directory where the .class file is and without ".class" for the parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're doing:

```
java -cp ... Share.class
```

Do

```
java -cp ... Share
```

Or if it's in a package

```
java -cp ... path.to.Share
```

You should not be supplying the class *file* as an argument, you should be supplying the fully qualified class *name.*

If your class is in the current directory and uses the default (empty) package, it will just be

```
java -cp . Share
```

or

```
java Share
```

The classpath is not used to point to the java executable, it's used to point to the various directories/jar files which contain your class files (at the root of the package structure).

### See also

- [java - the Java application launcher](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) (manual for invoking `java`)