# running a compiled java program on linux

Tags: java

I use eclipse for developing my applications.

I have 2 java files, one is main and one is class that is used by main.
In eclipse, I just execute as java program and it works. (default package).

Now I just want to run this program on linux and other windows.
How do I run it? if you can point to me a tutorial  that also is fine.

I am not looking at jar file/mainfest at this point of time . all I am looking for is to run thr program

Comment: You run the program the same with `java -cp {classpath} class`

Comment: @elyashiv no .java just classname is fine

Comment: possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378006/unable-to-run-compiled-classes-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way for you will likely be to export a runnable jar.

1. In eclipse, select your project.
2. Right click > export
3. Select "Runnable Jar"
4. Follow the wizard, be sure to choose the right run configuration.

Now a jar file should be saved which can be run by double clicking in a GUI or using the command line: `java -jar <your jar file>`

Comment: Thanks Tim this looks to be easier than I was thinking . in that there are 2 options: "Extract required libraries into generated jar" and package the required librariers in the generated jar' what is the difference

Comment: If I remember correctly, when a project relies on other JARs (like apache commons), eclipse can either unzip those JARs and copy the class files into the new one being created or simply place those JARs inside the new JAR. But I'm not sure... this particular tool becomes less useful since enterprise applications typically run in a container like JBoss, Tomcat, etc...

Answer (score 1):

If your class is called MainClass.class you just call

```
java MainClass
```

Answer (score 1):

**Basic way:** 
Locate your `java.exe` in the installed location e.g. `jdk/bin` folder.

Run your program simply as

without parameters

```
 jdk/bin/java yourMainProgramClass
```

with parameters param1 and param2, which get available to args variable of main(String[] args)

```
 jdk/bin/java yourMainProgramClass param1 param2
```

in the folder where both the `.class`(compilation output) files are present.

**Good way**:
Add `java.exe` or entire `jdkxxx/bin` folder in the path. Once done, run the program simply as

without parameters:

```
java yourMainProgramClass
```

with parameters param1 and param2, which get available to args variable of main(String[] args)

```
java yourMainProgramClass param1 param2
```

in the folder where both the `.class`(compilation output) files are present.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the located java file directory  execute with the command

> java yourMainProgram

if you need any jars to be specified in classpath use

```
 java -cp /path/to/jar yourMainprogram
```

[Document For Windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html)
        [Document For Linux](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/unix.html)